# Lumberjack not creating new file after MaxFileSize limit is exceeded

Tags: go, logging

I am using lumberjack logger in Golang to maintain Production server logs. Following are the configurations that I am using currently:

```
w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "abc.log",           // parameter
        MaxSize:    1,                  // megabytes
        MaxBackups: 0,
        MaxAge:     0,                 // days
    })
```

As expected, the logger should create new file once file size limit of 1 MB is exceeded. But it creates new file if it does not exist, but not if file size exceeds 1 MB limit. **After exceeding limit, no further logs are written in current but new file is also not created. To create a new file, I have to restart the server itself**. I am using Ubuntu here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: please share the full package name

Comment: I'd also add more details about what's that `zapcore` thing is. The way it calls out to `lumberjack`—whatever it is, too,—may explain misbehaviour (or not).

Comment: I think I'm seeing the same issue if this is github.com/natefinch/lumberjack

Comment: Did you solve this problem? You know if I can automatically create a new file with `Logrus`?